# How to take digits of PI as strings and return an array of the digits as numbers?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to take the first 1000 digits of pi as strings in an array and return them into a new array as digits:

```
from this: ["1","4","1","5","9","2"...] (the full array of numbers is already provided in my assignment)
to this: [1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2...]
```

I've tried creating a new variable with an empty array and using the .join method but when I console log it it returns the an empty array.

```
const strNums = ["1","4","1","5","9","2"...]
const newArray = [];
const integers = strNums.join(newArray);
console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: `.join()` creates a new array referenced by your `integers` variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
const input = ["1","4","1","5","9","2"];
const output = input.map(Number);
```